# Dynamic function call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, eval

Is there a better way of doing this to dynamically:

```js
function abcKY(a, no) {
  console.log(a + no);
}
function abcBC(a, no) {
  console.log(a - no);
}
var result_from_db = "abcKY";

eval(result_from_db)(1, 2);
```

I have multiple different requirements and I would like to standard like to make it configurable. So having a dynamic function call will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put inside of an object function mappings as key-function and call it using your variable `result_from_db`. Check this:

```js
var functions = {};
functions.abcKY = function(a, no) {
  console.log(a + no);
};
functions.abcBC = function(a, no) {
  console.log(a - no);
};
var result_from_db = "abcKY";
functions[result_from_db](1, 2);
```